# Browser scrollbar animation performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome

## In short:

Why is this:

```
$('body').animate({scrollLeft: 1000});
```

much much faster than this:

```
$('body').animate({"margin-left": 1000});
```

?

## Background:

I am working on a website that has a animated scrolling. e.g.: When the user clicks a link I fire a javascript that animates the scrollbar. Something similar to this website:

http://www.fashionphotographer.it/

My first take on this problem was to animate the `margin-left` using jQuery.animate but this proved to be very slow (my site is very content heavy). After that I tried animating the `left` of a absolute element, using CSS3 and even the -webkit-transform. All solutions where slow.

My last try was to use jQuery to animate the scrollbar, and this proved to be best solution so far.

My question is: What kind of optimization is the browser (I am using Chrome) doing under the hood that makes animating the scrollbar the best solution?

Comment: I noticed this last night because of a customer complaint.  He was using chrome and I had a .animate({opacity : 0}); that he claimed made the page unusable when he tried to scroll.  I just removed it for the time being.  I was also moving dom elements around too.  So I guess its the reflowing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the scrollLeft property will not force a reflow of the DOM, as you are really just changing which portion of the content is visible at any one time. margin-left, left or other smiliar properties, on the other hand, may cause other elements to resize, which forces the browser to reflow the DOM.

Edit: I believe scrollLeft will force a *repaint*, however this is much less intensive than a reflow. See http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/ for a good explanation of the difference.

Comment: I'd only add that if the OP wants it to work with margin-left, try writing your own animation function for animate that ticks less often but moves further. It's the easing option.

Comment: What about iframes? I also tried putting the content into iframes the updating the iframe scrollLeft. The performance was only marginally better than the margin-left.

Comment: @mattmanser I actually tried writing my own animation function using the requestAnimationFrame but didn't see any performance gains